# how can i declare a list of map defined types in cassandra

Tags: python, cql, cassandra-driver

i want to declare a list of objects in cassandra and i have already created the type object

```
CREATE TYPE profiles.educations (
    major text,
    end text,
    name text,
    degree text,
    start text,
    desce text
);
```

how can declare a list of map educations type
cause i have a json file this format:

```
{
...
"educations": [
    {
      "start": "2009",
      "major": "Business Administration and Management, General",
      "end": "2010",
      "name": "Gordon Institute of Business Science - University of Pretoria",
      "degree": "PDBA"
    },
    {
      "start": "2002",
      "major": "Marketing Management",
      "end": "2006",
      "name": "University of Pretoria/Universiteit van Pretoria",
      "degree": "B. com with specialization in Marketing Management"
    },
    {
      "major": "Finanzas",
      "end": "2013",
      "name": "Universidad de Los Andes",
      "degree": "Maestr\u00eda en Finanzas",
      "start": "2011",
      "desce": ""
    }]
...
}
```